# Calculating daily stock returns with some missing values

Tags: r, time-series, stocks

I have data like

```
date         price 
26-12-2015   112
25-12-2015   115
24-12-2015   119
23-12-2015   NA
22-12-2015   120
```

I want to calculate daily returns so the syntax using ttr package is

```
ROC(data$price, type="discrete")
```

The calculation will be (112-115)-1 and so on but it will show NA for date **23-12-2015**.

I want for when NA is present for previous date it should take price of the day before. I don't want to delete that row as I have dataframe with many other prices and I will lose that information.

Comment: Did you read the rules before posting? Doesnt look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to replace the NA by the price of the previous row, `na.locf` from `zoo` can be used (assuming that the dataset is `order`ered by 'date').

```
library(zoo)
df1$price <- na.locf(df1$price)
```